# UITableView unrecognized NumberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview, sections

i am getting this error.
I am working with SQLite. I have some data and i want to display the data in sections so i added a column that will be my section name, called "cittaTerritorio".
Now i am retrieving my data and sorting it using this column,
When i run the code everything crash with this message:

> -[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101c3ce50
>   2017-10-14 17:14:44.893258+0200 MinistryHelp[403:44322] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101c3ce50'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1812b3d38 0x1807c8528 0x1812c11f8 0x18aa7bcc4 0x1812b96e4 0x18119f0dc 0x18aa02cc8 0x18a7908d8 0x18a7900a4 0x18a78fe34 0x18a78fc44 0x18a81c14c 0x1008cfc60 0x1008cf040 0x1008cfedc 0x18a6c3bfc 0x18a76c128 0x18a76b5c8 0x18a76afcc 0x18a76aa34 0x18a76a95c 0x18a6c1000 0x1852910b4 0x185295194 0x185203f24 0x18522a340 0x18522b180 0x18125b8b8 0x181259270 0x18125982c 0x18117a2d8 0x18300bf84 0x18a727880 0x1008c62d0 0x180c9e56c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Have you any idea? That is my code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.listCitta()[section]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.territoriInCitta(section: section).count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.listCitta().count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.listCitta().count
}

func territoriInCitta(section: Int)-> [String]{
    let nomeSezione = tableview.headerView(forSection: section)?.textLabel?.text
    var listaCitta = [String]()
    listaCitta.removeAll()
    do{
        let territori = try self.database.prepare(territoryTable.filter(cittaTerritorio == nomeSezione!))
        for territorio in territori{
            listaCitta.append(territorio[self.cittaTerritorio])
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return listaCitta
}

func listCitta()-> [String]{ //aggiunge i vari nomi delle citta
    var listaCitta = [String]()
    listaCitta.removeAll()
    do{
        let terr = try self.database.prepare(territoryTable.select(cittaTerritorio))
        for territorio in terr{
            if listaCitta.contains(territorio[self.cittaTerritorio]){
                //nil
            }
            else{
                listaCitta.append(territorio[self.cittaTerritorio])
            }
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return listaCitta
}
```

with the first function i get the sections name based on the index of the list my method returns.
The second functions returns the number of the data based on the section so i filter the data based on that section name and than return the number using a list.
the third and the fourth method return the number of the sections.

I also tried inserting fake data, writing a number for test purpose, nothing went different.

Comment: The signature of `numberOfRowsInSection` is wrong. Comment out the method and retype it using code completion or look up the method in the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) documentation.

Comment: PS: And **never** do database operations in `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections`. These methods are called very often. Create a data source array and fetch your data once.

Comment: I saw that the problem was that somehow i had 2 numberOfRowsInSection methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't guess the correct signature for the method. There are two ways to get it right.

1. The best option is to let Xcode give you the correct signature. Start typing the name (such as "numberOfRows") and Xcode will show possible matching methods. Select the correct one.
2. The other option is to copy the correct signature from the reference documentation.

Here is the correct method signature:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

You are missing the underscore.

And why do you have two attempts at the `numberOfSections` method? Just use the correct one:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

Most likely you copied and pasted examples from some Swift 2 code. The APIs changes a lot in Swift 3.

Unrelated to your issue (as mentioned in the comments), do not call `listCitta()` from any of your table view data source or delegate methods. You should call that once (such as in `viewDidLoad`) and use a property to hold onto the array of results. Then your data source and delegate methods should simply access that property.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure implemented **UITableViewDelegate** and **UITableViewDataSource** in your respective view controller.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set all the delegates and data sources? if no, try this in viewDidLoad() method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     myTableView.delegate = self
     myTableView.dataSource = self
}
```

if this doesn't work for you, let me know, I will try to think more.